# How to create an if-statement to check if a button text has changed to a specific value c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a small program for a school project, but can't seem to find a solution at all.

I have been working on a windows forms with a label that displays a text. Then there are two buttons. If you a any of these buttons are clicked, the other is hidden and the text of the button that has been clicked changes.

Now I want to check if the text of any of these buttons has been changed and upon a second click on the now changed button close the application. Below is what I have so far.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "You wake up.\n\n"+
                      "What would you like to do?";

        button1.Text = "I'd like to eat some cerials!";
        button2.Text = "I need to go to the bathroom!";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "You stand up, go to the kitchen and eat some cerials. Nice!";
        button1.Text = "Hurray, you ate some cerials";
        button2.Hide();

        // if (button1.TextChanged +=)
        // {
        //     
        // }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "You don't finde the Bathroom in this house and have to use the garden.";
        button2.Text = "You get arested afterwars!";
        button1.Hide();
    }

    public void EndGame()
    {
        Close();
    }
```

Is there a way to actually do this or do I need some workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

- Create new web form application
- Create on Form1 button1,label1,textbox1
- Double click on form to add LoadEvent
- Double click on button to add click event

  ```
  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
  }

  //copy from here
  public class AppState
  {
      public string labelText { get; set; }
      public bool endGame { get; set; }
      public bool success { get; set; }
      public List<AppState> answers { get; set; }
  }

  AppState level = new AppState()
  {
      labelText = "You are ... you can go 1.left 2.right 3.further ",
      answers = new List<AppState>{
         new AppState() {
          labelText = "You are dead",
          endGame = true,
         },
         new AppState() {
          labelText = "You are winner",
          endGame = true,
          success = true
         },
         new AppState() {
          labelText = "You are bla bla.. 1. left 2. right",
          answers = new List<AppState>{
             new AppState() {
              labelText = "You are dead",
              endGame = true,
             },
             new AppState() {
              labelText = "You are winner",
              endGame = true,
              success = true
             }
          }
         }
        }
  };

  public void Render()
  {
      label1.Text = level.labelText;
      if (level.endGame)
      {
          button1.Enabled = false;
          if (level.success)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("winner");
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("looser");
          }
      }
  }

  public void Answer()
  {
      int ans = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
      level = level.answers[ans - 1];
      Render();
  }
  // copy to here        

  //this you need to do manualy with form editor
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Render();
  }

  //this you need to do manualy with form editor
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Answer();    
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice, mate. I will make sure to check it out afterwards

Comment: Made a new class and copied your code 100%. But it is still not working tho.

Comment: I get all kinds of errors, mate. But that does not mean it has somthing to do with your code, more with my skill.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways of doing this easily. One way is just have a global boolean value that shifts when I button is clicked. If your boolean is named `boolean endProgram = false`, then your if statement would look like this:

```
if(endProgram)
{
    EndGame()
}
```

Just in case you don't know this, `if(endProgram)` is the same thing is `if(endProgram == true)`. This only work with boolean values.

Just put the same thing into the other button click event and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks mate. Not at my PC right now but I will make sure to try it out! I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: Not sure if I do this the right way. I added the boolean and added the if statement to both button1_Click and button2_Click but it does not seem to do anything at all. Maybe I am doing this the wrong way?